# Mockito's thenAnswer with lambda

Tags: scala, mockito

So I've got this mock:

```
when(myMock.someMethod(anyString(), anyString(), anyString()))
                    .thenAnswer(new Answer[Path] {
                        override def answer(invocation: InvocationOnMock): Path =
                            temporaryFolder.getRoot.toPath.resolve(invocation.getArgument(2).asInstanceOf[String])
                    })
```

And this works just fine. However, doing some reading online, and based on suggestions from intelliJ, it seems like it would cleaner as this:

```
when(myMock.someMethod(anyString(), anyString(), anyString()))
                    .thenAnswer((invocation: InvocationOnMock) => 
                         temporaryFolder.getRoot.toPath.resolve(invocation.getArgument(2).asInstanceOf[String]))
```

However, when I try to compile this, I get a compilation error:

```
Error:(56, 50) type mismatch;
 found   : org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock => java.nio.file.Path
 required: org.mockito.stubbing.Answer[_]
                    .thenAnswer((invocation: InvocationOnMock) => temporaryFolder.getRoot.toPath.resolve(invocation.getArgument(2).asInstanceOf[String]))
```

Why? I don't even understand this message, does it not understand that the argument is a lambda?

I'm using mockito core 2.7.19.

Comment: The argument is not a method, it's a lambda. Lambdas can compile to functions or Single Abstract Method type instances, but the latter requires Scala 1.12. What is your Scala version?

Comment: Scala version is 2.11.11, so I feel like it should be supported. And true, I'll update my post.

Comment: Oops, I meant 2.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a lambda to create a Single Abstract Method type is a new feature in Scala 2.12. As you indicated in the comments, you are using 2.11. Consider upgrading, or you will be stuck using the long form.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

If you use the Scala version of mockito ([mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala)) you can write that in an even simpler way, so your code:

```
when(myMock.someMethod(anyString(), anyString(), anyString()))
                .thenAnswer((invocation: InvocationOnMock) => 
                     temporaryFolder.getRoot.toPath.resolve(invocation.getArgument(2).asInstanceOf[String]))
```

would become:

```
myMock.someMethod(*,*,*) shouldAnswer ((_: String, v: String) => temporaryFolder.getRoot.toPath.resolve(v))
```

Note that I'm just passing a standard Scala function that ignores the first argument and leaves out the third completely as you don't need it.

Disclaimer, I'm a maintainer of that library